# Access key values from list of dictionary YAML JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, yaml

I have a list of dictionaries in a YAML like so

```
- movies:
  api   : 'api name'
  key   : 'value of key'
- music:
  api   : 'api name'
  key   : 'value of key'
```

I'm using 'js-yaml' and reading from config.yml

```
var fs = require('fs');
var yaml = require('js-yaml');
var config = yaml.safeLoad(fs.readFileSync('./config.yml'));
...
app.get('/api/hello', (req, res) => {
  let hello = { homehost: 'Hello'};
  res.json(config['movies']['api']); // doesnt work
  //res.json(config.movies['api']); doesnt work
  //res.json(config.movies.api); doesnt work
  //res.json(String(config.movies.api)); doesnt work
  //res.json(config); works but returns the full yaml
});
...
```

*returns `TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined`*

I want js to get the value of the `api` field under `movies` or `music` from `var config` without converting to json.
I tried different things but it's not working. If the yaml structure needs changing, please point me to it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `api` and `key` are supposed to be under the `movies`/`music` keys, then you need to indent them correctly:

```
- movies:
    api   : 'api name'
    key   : 'value of key'
- music:
    api   : 'api name'
    key   : 'value of key'
```

This is a list of dictionaries of dictionaries, and equivalent to the following JSON:

```
[
  {
    "movies": { "api": "api name", "key": "value of key" }
  },
  {
    "music": { "api": "api name", "key": "value of key" }
  }
]
```

That doesn't seem to match what you want, though. From your usage `config['movies']` you just want a dictionary (of dictionaries), not a list:

```
movies:
  api   : 'api name'
  key   : 'value of key'
music:
  api   : 'api name'
  key   : 'value of key'
```

Comment: actually, it was indented correctly but didnt work. Removed the '-' before the yaml got it working. thanks